# Can I move some DAO token to another account to vote twice?

Tags: accounts, tokens, the-dao, voting

If I split my DAO tokens to 2 accounts before voting, will I be able to vote twice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you will,

that said it's useless, suppose you have 10 tokens, your say in the DAO is 10 over 100 issued tokens.

if you split in half, you'll have 2 votes of 5 tokens each, so at best you'll vote yes for 5+5 which is exactly what you'll have done if you kept your 10 tokens, at worst you'll cancel your own voting power by voting yay with the 5 tokens and nay to the 5 others ;)

Comment: So, if I want to vote for two separate proposals at the same time, I'll have to split my balance into two accounts as token are locked during the vote, but then I will have only half power for each vote. Does that mean that if two important votes take place at the same time, we have to choose between one or the other if we want to be able to vote with our full balance power ?

Comment: @NMassart No, you can vote on multiple different proposals with the same tokens.

Comment: @Nick Johnson But I read in http://www.coindesk.com/the-law-of-the-dao/ that "The voting investor has the ability to irrevocably vote once per proposal, and a vote freezes that investor’s DAO tokens." under "Why voting might be The DAO’s Achilles Heel?" section. So what's that freeze thing ? Doesn't it mean that you can't use your tokens for another vote if they are engaged in a running vote already ? Or should I open a new question...

Comment: Right, "once per proposal", not "once". Freezing means you can't withdraw, transfer, or split your tokens until all the votes they're participating in have closed.